# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {zip})

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error when using this code:

```
 const App = () => {

  const user = {name: "ff", address: {zip: "Henry street"}};

  const zip = user ? user.address: undefined ? user.address.zip : undefined;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>bnm {zip}</div>  
    </div>
  );

}
```

When I output the zip variable it shows this: {zip: "Henry street"}
This error goes away and it prints out the proper thing when I do this:

```
 const zip = (user ? user.address: undefined) ? user.address.zip : undefined;
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't work without the parentheses?

Comment: React can't display objects as children. You need to set a key to access

Comment: @underscore How do I set a key exactly? (I'm somewhat new to Javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anybody know why it doesn't work without the parentheses?

Because of [operator associativity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The conditional operator has *right-to-left* associativity. You can think of this as if the operator is trying to find the longest valid expression after the colon and uses that as the alternative value.
Thus your expression is evaluated as

```
user ? user.address : (undefined ? user.address.zip : undefined)
```

I.e. if `user` is "truthy", `user.address` is returned, which is the object mentioned in the error.

The precedence/associativity is not always obvious or well known, therefore its useful to add parenthesis to make the order of evaluation clearer even if doesn't change it.

There are clearer and less error prone ways to express the same logic:

You can use the optional chaining operator:

```
const zip = user?.address?.zip;
```

Or you can use a plain old `if` statement:

```
let zip;
if (user && user.address) {
  zip = user.address.zip;
}
```